# vba Excel Finding and using name of caller sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a mess of buttons that call the same function (kind of like a switchboard) and that in turn sends the details onto other functions (my categories).

On the other end of this, I have another function that is being called by a number of different functions. Depending on which category the caller function is, the function will do different things and return an answer.

Buttons (A/B/C/D/E) -> Switchboard function -> Functions (X/Y/Z) -> End function

I am looking for a way to simplify the code in my end function: instead of individual 'If (passed variable = x) then y' checks, I want to just check if the caller was function X.

All I seem to be able to find when I search for callers is Application.Caller, which returns the original caller (Button A). Is it possible to find the immediate function that is calling and use it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682932/how-to-inspect-call-stack

Comment: Alright, so I'm assuming by that you mean this isn't possible in excel either. Guess I'll just stick with my current system then, thanks